# Some basic questions about entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I've been watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YM-uykVfq_E) to understand entropy, and have a few follow-up questions.

1. So if I'm understanding things correctly, entropy is *a measure of the probability of a given entropy state*? If that's the case, then we could say that, semantically, a cool coffee cup with hot water inside has low entropy, and a lukewarm cup with lukewarm water inside has high(er) entropy?
2. I understand that the chance of something getting *visibly* warmer is statistically improbable. However, wouldn't the quanta of energy jumping around mean that there are constant fluctuations in heat? ie: if you had a precise enough thermometer in the hot water, you'd be able to see the temperature rise and fall infinitesimally small degrees (while trending down)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right. Moving heat from a hotter place to a colder place increases entropy. So if hot water in a cup cools down by giving heat to the cup itself, heating the cup up until they're the same temperature, that increases entropy. The entropy of the water goes down as it cools, but the entropy of the cup goes up by a greater amount. However, in a real system we need to be careful about that. Hot water will mostly cool by evaporation. That would increase the entropy of the surrounding air by a lot, but decrease the entropy of the remaining water. So it's possible that the entropy of a cup of hot water goes down as it cools, if for example the entropy of the surrounding air is going up a lot.
2. Yes, those sorts of small fluctuations do indeed occur. For a system with $N$ particles, the size of these sorts of fluctuations for so-called "intensive quantities" (things like temperature, pressure, or other things that don't change as the system size changes) is proportional to $1/\sqrt{N}.$  So for a thermometer with $10^{20}$ molecules the fluctuations in temperature are $1/\sqrt{10^{20}} = 10^{-10}$ as large as for a single molecule. That's why these fluctuations can't be measured in everyday contexts.